# How to map types to values in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, types

I think that in Scala `Map[Class[_ <: SomeSuperClass], V]` creates an immutable map such that `K` is `classOf[T]` where `T` is a direct or indirect subclass of `SomeSuperClass`. I could be wrong on this, and that may or may not be relevant to my question.

I'm finding that I can't really access the `V` values. How can I map the subclasses of `SomeSuperClass` to the `V` values?

For example, playing cards. In blackjack, jacks, queens and kings are all valued the same as tens. But in other games, they might have distinct values, such as that a jack is valued at 11, a queen at 12 and a king at 13.

Given an abstract `Rank` classes and subclasses `Ace`, `Two`, `Three`, ..., `King`, in the `cards` package, a class in the `blackjack` package could have a function like this:

```
def valueOf(rank: Rank): Int = rank match {
  case _: Ace => 11 // TODO: Figure out when value 1
  case _: King => 10
  case _: Queen => 10
  case _: Jack => 10
  case _: Ten => 10
  case _: Nine => 9
  case _: Eight => 8
  // etc.
}
```

In Java, I would (and did) just use an enumerated type. There's something called sealed classes in Scala, but that seems to actually be a lot more trouble than enumerations in Java. Or maybe I haven't figured out how to use them properly.

But I would much prefer a more flexible approach that allows me or anyone else to add card ranks, and valuations for those ranks with a minimum of fuss (e.g., by simply subclassing `Rank`). Something like this:

```
class Valuations(val map: Map[Class[_ <: Rank], Int]) {

  def valueOf(rank: Rank): Int = {
    val key = rank.getClass
    if (map.contains(key) map.get(key) else {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No match for " + rank.toString)
    }
  }

}
```

I can get IntelliJ to give me a green checkmark, but I can't get my unit tests to pass.

In the Java version of this, the enumerated type `Rank` has a value function, so you can rely on a `Rank` instance to have that valuation. But even if I don't want to add new card ranks, adding new mappings to values of types other than `int` might be clunky and not really in the spirit of the single responsibility principle.

Surely there's a more elegant solution in Scala. How can I match up these types as keys to values while maintaining the flexibility to add different subtypes without rewriting anything that already exists?

Comment: Scala 3 does have enums, if you're willing to try that out.

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI I am. But our industry that's still on Java 8? Maybe not.

Answer (score 5):

What you really want is a partial function from `Rank` to `Int`. Unlike total functions that are defined for all elements of the domain, partial functions can be defined for only some of them.

Also, if you don't mind another suggestion, throwing exceptions is not in the spirit of functional programming. I'm not imposing functional approach on you, since Scala is perfectly fine to be used in an object oriented (Java-like) manner. But I'm going to suggest it. And it says - don't throw! I always say that throwing is like completely tearing the fabric of your program. It rips the walls and says "welp, now I'm taking a shortcut". It's almost like goto statements. If you decide to use exceptions anyway, I'm pretty sure you can rework my example to incorporate them.

My suggestion is, instead of throwing, make it explicit that your function could end up with error value as a result. You can easily do that using `Either[MyErrorType, MyValueType]`. That way, the value you eventually return needs to be either `Left(instanceOfMyErrorType)` or `Right(instanceOfMyValueType)`. And later, in some code that needs to handle errors, you can always inspect whether you have a `Right` or a `Left` in your hands, and act accordingly (e.g. in case of Left log an error and return a 400 HTTP response or whatever).

Here's the code:

```
sealed trait Rank
case object Ace extends Rank
case object King extends Rank
case object Queen extends Rank
case object Jack extends Rank
case object Ten extends Rank
// ...

final case class Error(msg: String)

val exampleMapping: PartialFunction[Rank, Int] = 
  (rank: Rank) => rank match {
    case Ace => 11 
    case King => 10
    case Queen => 10
    case Jack => 10
    // No Ten!
  }

def valuations(rank: Rank, f: PartialFunction[Rank, Int]): Either[Error, Int] =
  f.andThen(rank => Right(rank)).applyOrElse(
    rank,
    (v: Rank) => Left(Error(s"No such element: $v"))
  )

val a = valuations(King, exampleMapping) // Right(10)
val b = valuations(Ten, exampleMapping)  // Left(Error(No such element: Ten))
```

The most interesting part in the code above is the `valuations` method. Here's what it does:

- Give me a `rank: Rank` and a partial function from `Rank` to `Int` and I will either return an `Int` or an `Error`
- What I do now is, I compose the provided function with the one that turns that value into `Right(thatInteger)` (or, in mathematical terms, compose the latter with the former; `f andThen g` means `g(f(x))` whereas `f compose g` means `f(g(x))`... I always find it mentally easier to use `andThen`)
- Apply the composition defined above to the `rank` argument, and if that function didn't have a defined outcome for `rank`, well, then return `Left(error)`

And of course, you can have many different such partial functions, other users can define their own, etc. Note two things though:

- Using sealed trait means that nobody can extend `Rank`. This makes sense to me. But if you want to be able not only to add different mappings later, but even add new `Rank`s, then simply don't make the trait sealed.
- Make your case classes [final](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/tricky_behaviours/final_case_classes.html) because they should not be extended, and by making them final, compiler will warn you if you try to define a total function (not partial!), but forget to handle some cases by accidentally omitting a `case` for some rank. With case objects, it's okay if you mark them as final too, but it's not mandatory since they can't be extended anyway (they can have only one instance, like singleton in Java).

If for whatever reason you decide later that you don't want to return errors when a mapping is undefined, but instead you want to use a default mapping which has all the default values for all the ranks (= it's not a partial function `Rank => Int`, but a total one), then this would be easy to do as well. Try it for practice!

As a final note, Scala 3 will have really nice enums, which is something you say you're familiar with from Java, and which Scala 2 lacks.

Comment: Huh. A sealed trait with case objects. I did think about case objects, but I wouldn't have thought of using them with a trait this way. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. What do you think about the partial function solution?

Comment: I have to read up on partial functions, I don't recall Cay Horstmann mentioning them in his classic book. Seems like an easy enough concept, though.

Comment: I'm pretty confident they're in every Scala book, plus it's not a concept reserved for Scala only. But you can make it work with a Map too, just make sure to use a simple `Map[Rank, Int]` instead of `Map[Class[_ <: Rank], Int]`. And instead of doing `rank.getClass`, you can always simply pattern match on the rank, e.g. `rank match { case Ace => ..., case King => ... }`

Comment: `Map[Rank, Int]`? Now I'm thinking I may have over-complicated this whole thing.

Comment: I do see that Horstmann's book does mention partial functions, and fairly early on. Maybe I skipped over it somehow. Maybe he doesn't explain it all that well. Either way, I need to sit down and reread that book.

Answer (score 3):

I think @slouc answer is good (algebraic data types(ADTs) / sealed traits, error as values, etc) but you really should avoid partial function (with exception to certain methods like `List#collect` that doesn't fail on undefined inputs) and work with total functions as much as possible. You could make `exampleMapping` into a `Rank => Option[Int]` but I think you should just use a map instead.

```scala
sealed trait Rank
object Rank {
  //It's up to you if you want to nest these
  case object Ace extends Rank
  case object King extends Rank
  case object Queen extends Rank
  case object Jack extends Rank
  case object Ten extends Rank
  case object Nine extends Rank
  //...
}

val exampleMapping = Map(
  Rank.Ace -> 11,
  Rank.King -> 10,
  Rank.Queen -> 10,
  Rank.Jack -> 10,
  Rank.Ten -> 10
)

def valuations(rank: Rank, m: Map[Rank, Int]): Either[Error, Int] =
  m.get(rank).toRight(new Error(s"No such element: $rank"))
```

If you don't actually need variable mappings (or if the mappings are known at compile-time it is also good to implement them as separate rank types) then you should just implement values within (isn't this more enum like?):

```scala
sealed abstract class Rank(val maybeValue: Option[Int])
object Rank {
  case object Ace extends Rank(Some(11))
  case object King extends Rank(Some(10))
  case object Queen extends Rank(Some(10))
  case object Jack extends Rank(Some(10))
  case object Ten extends Rank(Some(10))
  case object Nine extends Rank(None)
  //...
}

def valuations(rank: Rank): Either[Error, Int] =
  rank.maybeValue.toRight(new Error(s"No such element: $rank"))
```

And if values aren't optional (like Java enums...):

```scala
sealed abstract class Rank(val value: Int)
object Rank {
  case object Ace extends Rank(11)
  case object King extends Rank(10)
  case object Queen extends Rank(10)
  case object Jack extends Rank(10)
  case object Ten extends Rank(10)
  case object Nine extends Rank(9)
  //...
}

//we wouldn't even need errors here if they weren't optional, and this method is kind of pointless now...
def valuations(rank: Rank): Int = rank.value
```

And now with multiple rank types you could generify with subtyping (which breaks your ADT) (wait, can we even subclass Java enums in the first place?)

```scala
def valuations[A <: SuperRank](rank: A): Int = rank.value
```

but what you could also do is to have something like a `RankValue` typeclass with multiple instances for different rank ADTs

```scala
//there exist a `RankValue` typeclass instance that maps rank of A to value of B
def valuations[A, B: RankValue[A, *]](rank: A): B = rank.valueOf
```

but I think I should stop here, I'm going off on too many tagents...